# Bootstrap Prepend Icon to Select List

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-select

Using Bootstrap (v2.0.4), i'm trying to prepend an icon to a select list - I can't get the placement correct. I'm unable to update Bootstrap to a newer version at this stage, must use v2.0.4

I've looked through the [docs](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v2.0.4/docs/base-css.html#forms) but can't see any mention of it.

I have included my code snippet below and a link to a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/45yjf2z1/2/);

```html
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<hr>
<div class="control-group">
 <div class="controls">
  <div class="input-prepend">
   <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-question-sign"></i></span> <select class="input-xlarge">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="control-group">
 <div class="controls">
  <div class="input-prepend">
   <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span><input type="text">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give position absolute to you class add-on and make the parent class Relative. Just add the below css and it will work properly ;)

```
  .input-prepend input, .input-append input, .input-prepend select,
 .input-append select, .input-prepend .uneditable-input, .input-append
 .uneditable-input {
         padding-left: 30px;
     }


    span.add-on {
    position: absolute;
    left: 1px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
     .input-prepend {
         position: relative;
     }
```

Comment: Thanks @Jatin Kathuria The trouble with that is I can't see the text after I have selected it! Try it yourself in the fiddle. The placement works well though. Any ideas?

Comment: give padding-left to the select box and text box with some class and it will work :)